# S3 multipart upload with encryption

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to implement multiple upload request with an encryption. First of all I send InitiateMultipartUploadRequest. It get me an upload id. Then I split my file by chunks and send UploadPartRequest.

Function of creating s3 client:

```
public IAmazonS3 CreateAmazonS3Client()
{
    byte[] IV = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };
    var s3Config = new AmazonS3CryptoConfigurationV2(SecurityProfile.V2)
    {
        ServiceURL = "_URL_",
        ForcePathStyle = true
    };

    var aes = Aes.Create();
    aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
    aes.IV = IV;

    using (var hashSha256 = new SHA256Managed())
    {
        aes.Key = hashSha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("_PASSWORD_"));
    }

    return new AmazonS3EncryptionClientV2("_ACCESS_KEY_", "_SECRET_KEY_", s3Config, new EncryptionMaterialsV2(aes, SymmetricAlgorithmType.AesGcm));
}
```

Function of uploading chunks:

```
private async Task<UploadPartResponse> UploadFileChunkAsync(string key, string uploadId, byte[] buffer, int partNumber, SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim)
{
    using var s3Client = CreateAmazonS3Client();
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();

    var bufferSize = partNumber < buffer.Length / _chunkSize ? _chunkSize : buffer.Length % _chunkSize;

    lock (_syncObj)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, partNumber * _chunkSize, bufferSize);
        stream.Position = 0;
    }

    var uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
    {
        Key = key,
        BucketName = "_BACKET_NAME_",
        UploadId = uploadId,
        PartNumber = partNumber + 1,
        InputStream = stream,
        PartSize = bufferSize,
    };

    return await s3Client.UploadPartAsync(uploadRequest);
}
```

UploadFileChunkAsync function throw an exception on the last return line (UploadPartAsync). The exception message is: "The given key '*UPLOAD_ID*' was not present in the dictionary"

What does it mean, where the key must be placed?